# Strange console.log behaviour with object and it's field

Tags: javascript, object, console.log

I have the strange behavior (as i think) of `console.log`. So, there is two `console.log` in my console, **first** shows `PdfViewerApplication` object, **second** shows it's fieid, named `eventBus`.
[image]
So, as you can see **second line** says that `PdfViewerApplication.eventBus` right?
Now lets look at **first line** (before! second) , expand the body of the object and find `eventBus` field.
[image]

Obviously it is not null there, it almost has 2 eventListeners (pagesloaded)!

How is it possible?

Comment: You're inspecting a live object. It may change _after_ having been logged.

Comment: Hover over the blue box with the `i`.

Comment: @deceze you are right! write it as answer

Comment: @FelixKling i was so close) thank you!